# Pendo Integration: Anonymize visitor after logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, integration, analytics, pendo

Just wanna `anonymize` the `initialized` pendo visitor after the `logout` button press on the app. Is it possible? Or is there no need to anonymize after logout? [Official documentation](https://developers.pendo.io/docs/?bash#overview) looks to be vague regarding it. Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `initialize` api with `nil/null` that should start anoint session